# Setting default value on a Symfony2 radio button choice field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have the following Symfony2 form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{   
    $builder
        ->add('submitter_is_home', 'choice', array(
            'expanded' => true,
            'choices' => array('1' => 'Home', '' => 'Away'),
            'data' => '1',
        ))  
    ;   
}
```

(I omitted my other fields for clarity.)

When I visit this form in the browser, the "Home" option is not selected. I checked the source, too, and it doesn't look like the proper attribute is set there, either.

Does the default value work differently for radio buttons than for other types of `choice` fields? What could be going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want an option to be selected the `empty_value` will not work.

The simply solution is to set a value to your object before adding the form (like `$myentity->setRadiobutton(1)`). Symfony will understand and add it as a selected value (works with choice type so might be the same with radio!)

Comment: It won't help with a form element set as 'property_path' => false.

Comment: and when you have form without entity ?

Comment: give an array to the form type instead of an object with as key the key in your form type and as value 1 or true (probably, didn't test it). Should do the trick

Comment: In my case, i used a 'choise' type field called 'type', without entity. Solution: $form->get('type')->setData('default_val');

Answer (score 1):

in your controller `newAction()`, befor `$form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);` add the default value like this `$entity->setSubmitter_is_home(1);`